# Determining available space within Storage Access Framework for 5.0+ OS ver

Tags: android

I have an application that allows the user to select their media destination via SAF using OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. As new media files are added, I would like to check to make sure there is a minimum amount of space rather than filling it up.  It is also could be used for selecting the amount of file cache if the size of the destination is known.

AFAIK, DocumentFile, etc., doesn't give you anything.  Technically, if you go through OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, the actual destination isn't known, while it could be the sdcard, it could also be a cloud destination.

However, maybe someone has done enough experimentation to reliably determine the flash drive being used.  If the user chooses the primary partition then it can be extracted from DocumentFile, at least I can excluded the primary space.  Sdcard mount points vary among devices so getting an accurate map might be problematic.

I can get the space of the sdcards available using the standard getFilesDir or getMediaFilesDir and use the file to get available space.

So how to find the space if you only have a DocumentFile object?

Comment: I've been investigating this.  What category and MIME type do you use when you build your intent with OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?  I haven't been able to find a combination that works.

Comment: Well...none, given it is a directory and not a file.  So just Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) then start the activity with result.  I'm able to acquire the directory and use it, just need the available space now.

Comment: @Bruce did you work this out?  Have the same problem myself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Ok, I have found some kind of solution. This was tested on android 5.1 set-top-box.
First, get the treeUri from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Then do the following:

```
    Uri docTreeUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(
            treeUri,
            DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri)
    );
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(docTreeUri, "r");
        assert pfd != null;
        StructStatVfs stats = Os.fstatvfs(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "block_size=" + stats.f_bsize + ", num_of_blocks=" + stats.f_bavail);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "free space in Megabytes:" + stats.f_bavail * stats.f_bsize / 1024 / 1024);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | ErrnoException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
```

Comment: Plase note that   this fails if Uri is Downloads uri

Comment: Thank you for posting this, works great for USB storage.  You need to close file descriptor or you'll get a crash your app when USB storage device is disconnected.  (Note: have only tested so far on Android Q).

Comment: Since this is a good answer for USB devices which I am looking for *everywhere for last couple of days* let me add few tags to help searches:
- how to get android usb otg device free space / free memory
- how to get android usb otg device total space / total memory
- get available space of USB devices in android

Comment: Additional information: Android class `android.os.StatFs` uses `statvfs`. Difference between `statvfs` and `fstatvfs` is here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatvfs.html In Android both methods returns `StructStatVfs`.

Comment: @tliebeck I got same issue. Thank u